# Java ExtentReports FreeMarker Template Error: freemarker.core._MiscTemplateException

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng, extentreports

ExtentReports doesn't work properly. I've been searching for a fix on web for this but couldn't find any.

**COMPLETE CODE:**

```
package tcankaya.ExtentReports;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentSparkReporter;

public class ExtentReportDemo {

    //extent object set globally
    ExtentReports extent;
    
    @BeforeTest
    public void config()
    {
        //Classnames ExtentReports, ExtentSparkReporter
        
        //ExtentSparkReporter is responsible for creaate an XML file and to do some configs
        String path = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//reports//index2.html";
        ExtentSparkReporter reporter = new ExtentSparkReporter(path);
        
        reporter.config().setReportName("Web Automation Results");
        reporter.config().setDocumentTitle("Test Results");
        
        //ExtentReports is the main class 
        //Attach your report to this main class - this class responsible to cretae and consolidate all ur test execution
        extent = new ExtentReports();
        // our main class has knowledge of our object reporter
        extent.attachReporter(reporter);
        extent.setSystemInfo("Tester", "Talha Cankaya");    
    }
    
    @Test
    public void initialDemo()
    {
        // this step is mandatory in each test we have to give extent knowledge
        ExtentTest test = extent.createTest("Initial Demo");    
        
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        
        driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        
        
        // this step is also mandatory to end of execution
        extent.flush();
    }
    
}
```

**POM XML FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>tcankaya</groupId>
  <artifactId>ExtentReports</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>ExtentReports</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
      

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.freemarker/freemarker -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.32</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.8.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
  </dependencies>
  
  

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

**CONSOLE OUTPUT:**

> Aug 10, 2023 3:38:51 PM freemarker.log._JULLoggerFactory$JULLogger
> error SEVERE: Error executing FreeMarker template FreeMarker template
> error: Template inclusion failed (for parameter value
> "partials/except�on.ftl"): Template not found for name
> "spark/partials/except�on.ftl". The name was interpreted by this
> TemplateLoader:
> ClassTemplateLoader(resourceLoaderClass=com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports,
> basePackagePath="templates/" /* relatively to resourceLoaderClass pkg
> */).
>
> ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
>
> - Failed at: #include "partials/${view.toString()}...  [in template "spark/spark.spa.ftl" at line 27, column 36]
>
> ---
>
> Java stack trace (for programmers):
> ---- freemarker.core._MiscTemplateException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...]    at
> freemarker.core.Include.accept(Include.java:164)  at
> freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:371)   at
> freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executedNestedContentForCollOrSeqListing(IteratorBlock.java:321)
> at
> freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executeNestedContent(IteratorBlock.java:271)
> at
> freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.accept(IteratorBlock.java:244)
> at
> freemarker.core.Environment.visitIteratorBlock(Environment.java:645)
> at
> freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.acceptWithResult(IteratorBlock.java:108)
> at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:94)  at
> freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:335)   at
> freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:341)   at
> freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:314)     at
> freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:383)   at
> com.aventstack.extentreports.templating.FreemarkerTemplate.processTemplate(FreemarkerTemplate.java:52)
> at
> com.aventstack.extentreports.templating.FreemarkerTemplate.getSource(FreemarkerTemplate.java:39)
> at
> com.aventstack.extentreports.templating.FreemarkerTemplate.writeTemplate(FreemarkerTemplate.java:45)
> at
> com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.AbstractFileReporter.processTemplate(AbstractFileReporter.java:74)
> at
> com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentSparkReporter.flush(ExtentSparkReporter.java:149)
> at
> com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentSparkReporter$1.onNext(ExtentSparkReporter.java:121)
> at
> com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentSparkReporter$1.onNext(ExtentSparkReporter.java:113)
> at
> io.reactivex.rxjava3.subjects.PublishSubject$PublishDisposable.onNext(PublishSubject.java:310)
> at
> io.reactivex.rxjava3.subjects.PublishSubject.onNext(PublishSubject.java:226)
> at
> com.aventstack.extentreports.ReactiveSubject.onFlush(ReactiveSubject.java:83)
> at
> com.aventstack.extentreports.AbstractProcessor.onFlush(AbstractProcessor.java:95)
> at
> com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports.flush(ExtentReports.java:279)
> at
> tcankaya.ExtentReports.ExtentReportDemo.initialDemo(ExtentReportDemo.java:51)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)   at
> org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
> at
> org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:664)
> at
> org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:227)
> at
> org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
> at
> org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:957)
> at
> org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:200)
> at
> org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
> at
> org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)   at
> org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:848)     at
> org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)    at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:443)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:437)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:397)   at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:336)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)   at
> org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1280)     at
> org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1200)  at
> org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1114)     at
> org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1082)   at
> org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
> at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
> at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77) Caused
> by: freemarker.template.TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found
> for name "spark/partials/except�on.ftl". The name was interpreted by
> this TemplateLoader:
> ClassTemplateLoader(resourceLoaderClass=com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports,
> basePackagePath="templates/" /* relatively to resourceLoaderClass pkg
> */).  at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:2957)
> at
> freemarker.core.Environment.getTemplateForInclusion(Environment.java:3062)
> at freemarker.core.Include.accept(Include.java:162)     ... 50 more
>
> Aug 10, 2023 3:38:51 PM
> com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentSparkReporter flush
> SEVERE: An exception occurred FreeMarker template error: Template
> inclusion failed (for parameter value "partials/except�on.ftl"):
> Template not found for name "spark/partials/except�on.ftl". The name
> was interpreted by this TemplateLoader:
> ClassTemplateLoader(resourceLoaderClass=com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports,
> basePackagePath="templates/" /* relatively to resourceLoaderClass pkg
> */).
>
> ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
>
> - Failed at: #include "partials/${view.toString()}...  [in template "spark/spark.spa.ftl" at line 27, column 36]
>
> ---
>
> Java stack trace (for programmers):
> ---- freemarker.core._MiscTemplateException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...]    at
> freemarker.core.Include.accept(Include.java:164)  at
> freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:371)   at
> freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executedNestedContentForCollOrSeqListing(IteratorBlock.java:321)
> at
> freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executeNestedContent(IteratorBlock.java:271)
> at
> freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.accept(IteratorBlock.java:244)
> at
> freemarker.core.Environment.visitIteratorBlock(Environment.java:645)
> at
> freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.acceptWithResult(IteratorBlock.java:108)
> at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:94)  at
> freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:335)   at
> freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:341)   at
> freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:314)     at
> freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:383)   at
> com.aventstack.extentreports.templating.FreemarkerTemplate.processTemplate(FreemarkerTemplate.java:52)
> at
> com.aventstack.extentreports.templating.FreemarkerTemplate.getSource(FreemarkerTemplate.java:39)
> at
> com.aventstack.extentreports.templating.FreemarkerTemplate.writeTemplate(FreemarkerTemplate.java:45)
> at
> com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.AbstractFileReporter.processTemplate(AbstractFileReporter.java:74)
> at
> com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentSparkReporter.flush(ExtentSparkReporter.java:149)
> at
> com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentSparkReporter$1.onNext(ExtentSparkReporter.java:121)
> at
> com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentSparkReporter$1.onNext(ExtentSparkReporter.java:113)
> at
> io.reactivex.rxjava3.subjects.PublishSubject$PublishDisposable.onNext(PublishSubject.java:310)
> at
> io.reactivex.rxjava3.subjects.PublishSubject.onNext(PublishSubject.java:226)
> at
> com.aventstack.extentreports.ReactiveSubject.onFlush(ReactiveSubject.java:83)
> at
> com.aventstack.extentreports.AbstractProcessor.onFlush(AbstractProcessor.java:95)
> at
> com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports.flush(ExtentReports.java:279)
> at
> tcankaya.ExtentReports.ExtentReportDemo.initialDemo(ExtentReportDemo.java:51)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)   at
> org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
> at
> org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:664)
> at
> org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:227)
> at
> org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
> at
> org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:957)
> at
> org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:200)
> at
> org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
> at
> org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)   at
> org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:848)     at
> org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)    at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:443)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:437)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:397)   at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:336)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)   at
> org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1280)     at
> org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1200)  at
> org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1114)     at
> org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1082)   at
> org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
> at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
> at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77) Caused
> by: freemarker.template.TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found
> for name "spark/partials/except�on.ftl". The name was interpreted by
> this TemplateLoader:
> ClassTemplateLoader(resourceLoaderClass=com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports,
> basePackagePath="templates/" /* relatively to resourceLoaderClass pkg
> */).  at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:2957)
> at
> freemarker.core.Environment.getTemplateForInclusion(Environment.java:3062)
> at freemarker.core.Include.accept(Include.java:162)     ... 50 more

PASSED: tcankaya.ExtentReports.ExtentReportDemo.initialDemo

```
 Default test
 Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
```

Default suite Total tests run: 1, Passes: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0